# Find a sequence of integer powers faster than the naive algorithm

Tags: algorithms, arithmetic

Let $k\in \mathbb{N}$ be fixed. The naive way to compute a sequence of values $a_1^k,\ldots,a_n^k$ where $a_i\in \mathbb{N}$ for all $1\leq i\leq n$ is compute $a_i^k$ individually with the exponentiation by squaring. This takes a total of $O(n\log k)$ multiplications.

Is this optimal? What if for each $a_i$, we have $\frac{1}{c} a_i \leq a_{i+1}\leq c a_i$.

I come up with this question because I was doing a binary search over $f(n)=n^k$.

Comment: Why is the number of multiplications optimal if $a_{i+1} = a_i^k$?

Comment: If you know that $a_{i+1} = a_i^k$ then we have to find just value of $a_n^k$ which means is $O(n+\log k)$.

Comment: I was wrong, thanks for point it out. That is actually the best possible situation...

Comment: You can also try $a^b = \exp(b\log a)$ if you don't need exact results.

Comment: There are various methods for batch exponentiation that use fewer multiplications than the obvious method.  They have been studied in the cryptography literature; you might explore the crypto literature on speeding up exponentiation.  Cryptographers study exponentiation mod p, so you might need to check whether all of their speedups also apply over the integers as well.

Comment: I don't know what "doing a binary search over $f(n) = n^k$" means.

Comment: @D.W. Do you think that you can add a useful answer?

Answer (score 1):

In the worst case, this seems to be optimal. If your $a_i$ are pairwise coprime,
e.g. $k$ different primes, they powers do not share any factors.

Of course, if $k$ is large but $c$ from your proposed restriction is small, there 
may not be such a set; then, you powers share factors. You *could* exploit this
if you knew the shared factors for your $a_i$; but finding those is harder than
just computing all the powers.

So I daresay, no, you can not do this faster without more knowledge about the $a_i$.

Comment: Finding the shared factors can be done with GCD, which (depending on how big $k$ is) could be faster than computing the powers. In the case the $a_i$ are coprime you could compute (a_i * a_{i+1})^k and then reduce mod $a_{i+1}$ or mod $a_i$ to get either $a_{i+1}^k$ or $a_i^k$ but that is not any faster either.

Comment: @TomvanderZanden True, GCD is sufficient for *some* speedup. I thought you'd have to factor the $a_i$, but that's not strictly necessary. That said, [the probability that the $a_i$ are set-wise coprime is quite high](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime#Probabilities).